# Does not show data when loading XML on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML and I want it to look like a table in sql, this is the structure

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GenerateReportResponse 
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
     <GenerateReportResult>
        <Data>
           <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
              <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                 <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                       <xs:element name="Table">
                          <xs:complexType>
                             <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Registro" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Campania" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Instancia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Intentos" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Duración_x0020_Total" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Duración_x0020_Preview" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Duración_x0020_Llamada" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Estado_x0020_Registro" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Estado_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Último_x0020_Teléfono_x0020_Marcado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Bonificación_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Fecha_x0020_Hora_x0020_Agenda" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Teléfono_x0020_Agenda" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Fecha_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Hora_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Resultado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Observaciones" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Usuario_x0020_Asignado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="EtiquetaCallCopyUser3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="EtiquetaCallCopyUser4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="EtiquetaCallCopyUser10" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="EtiquetaCallCopyUser11" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="EtiquetaCallCopyUser12" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="EtiquetaCallCopyUser13" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Fecha_x0020_Creación" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Hora_x0020_Creación" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Grupo_x0020_Inicia_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Grupo_x0020_Finaliza_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Origen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Versión_x0020_Encuesta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Estado_x0020_QA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Grupo_x0020_Negocio" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Grupo_x0020_Llamada" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Gestión" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="CodCliente" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Nombre_x0020_Establecimiento" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Responsable_x0020_Negocio" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Cliente_x0020__x0028_D_x002F_E_x0029_" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ABC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Sector" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Gerencia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Frecuencia_x0020_de_x0020_llamada" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Telefono_x0020_Movil_x0020_1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Telefono_x0020_Movil_x0020_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Telefono_x0020_Fijo_x0020_1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Telefono_x0020_Fijo_x0020_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Telefono_x0020_Adicional_x0020__x0028_M_x0020_o_x0020_F_x0029_" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Ciudad" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Disponible1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Disponible2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                             </xs:sequence>
                          </xs:complexType>
                       </xs:element>
                    </xs:choice>
                 </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
           </xs:schema>
           <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
              <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                 <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                    <Registro>1</Registro>
                    <Campania>*****</Campania>
                    <Instancia>*****</Instancia>
                    <Intentos>4</Intentos>
                    <Duración_x0020_Total>236</Duración_x0020_Total>
                    <Duración_x0020_Preview>243</Duración_x0020_Preview>
                    <Duración_x0020_Llamada>0</Duración_x0020_Llamada>
                    <Estado_x0020_Registro>Registro Gestionado</Estado_x0020_Registro>
                    <Estado_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>No Efectivo</Estado_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Último_x0020_Teléfono_x0020_Marcado>*******</Último_x0020_Teléfono_x0020_Marcado>
                    <Bonificación_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>0</Bonificación_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_1>CERRADO POR INTENTOS</Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_1>
                    <Fecha_x0020_Gestión>16/05/2019</Fecha_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Hora_x0020_Gestión>18:42:29</Hora_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación>********</Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación>
                    <Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación>*******</Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación>
                    <Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación>*****</Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación>
                    <Usuario_x0020_Asignado>******</Usuario_x0020_Asignado>
                    <Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado>******</Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado>
                    <Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado>*****</Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado>
                    <Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>*****</Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>*******</Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>*****</Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Fecha_x0020_Creación>16/05/2019</Fecha_x0020_Creación>
                    <Hora_x0020_Creación>09:43:29</Hora_x0020_Creación>
                    <Grupo_x0020_Finaliza_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>SALUDO</Grupo_x0020_Finaliza_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión>
                    <Origen>Archivo de Carga</Origen>
                    <Versión_x0020_Encuesta>1</Versión_x0020_Encuesta>
                    <Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta>17/08/2016</Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta>
                    <Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta>14:56:05</Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta>
                    <Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga>4</Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga>
                    <Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga>08/02/2019</Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga>
                    <Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga>08:48:00</Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga>
                    <Estado_x0020_QA>Ninguno</Estado_x0020_QA>
                    <Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Gestión>******</Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Gestión>
                    <CodCliente>*****</CodCliente>
                    <Nombre_x0020_Establecimiento>**********</Nombre_x0020_Establecimiento>
                    <Responsable_x0020_Negocio>********</Responsable_x0020_Negocio>
                    <Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Cliente_x0020__x0028_D_x002F_E_x0029_>***</Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Cliente_x0020__x0028_D_x002F_E_x0029_>
                    <ABC>***</ABC>
                    <Gerencia>******</Gerencia>
                    <Frecuencia_x0020_de_x0020_llamada>*********</Frecuencia_x0020_de_x0020_llamada>
                    <Ciudad>*********</Ciudad>
                    <Disponible1>*******</Disponible1>
                    <Disponible2>*********</Disponible2>
                 </Table>
              </NewDataSet>
           </diffgr:diffgram>
        </Data>
        <Error_Number>0</Error_Number>
     </GenerateReportResult>
  </GenerateReportResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap,
                'http://TPColTPMarketing.teleperformance.co' AS ns, 
                'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' AS dg)
SELECT
 XC.value('Registro[1]','BIGINT') as Registro
,XC.value('Campania[1]','varchar(500)') as Campania
,XC.value('Instancia[1]','varchar(500)') as Instancia
,XC.value('Intentos[1]','INT') as Intentos
,XC.value('Duración_x0020_Total[1]','int') as DuracionTotal 
,XC.value('Duración_x0020_Preview[1]','int') as DuracionPreview
,XC.value('Duración_x0020_Llamada[1]','int') as DuracionLlamada
,XC.value('Estado_x0020_Registro[1]', 'varchar(500)') as EstadoRegistro 
,XC.value('Estado_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Estado_UltimaGestion
,XC.value('Último_x0020_Teléfono_x0020_Marcado[1]','varchar(500)') as UltimoTelefonoMarcado 
,XC.value('Bonificación_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'int') as Bonificacion_UltimaGestion 
,XC.value('Fecha_x0020_Hora_x0020_Agenda[1]', 'datetime') as BonificacionHoraAgenda 
,XC.value('Teléfono_x0020_Agenda[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TelefonoAgenda 
,XC.value('Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_1[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GestionNivel_1 
,XC.value('Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_2[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GestionNivel_2 
,XC.value('Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_3[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GestionNivel_3 
,XC.value('Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_4[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GestionNivel_4 
,XC.value('Gestión_x0020_Nivel_x0020_5[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GestionNivel_5 
,XC.value('Fecha_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as FechaGestion 
,XC.value('Hora_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as HoraGestion 
,XC.value('Resultado[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Resultado
,XC.value('Observaciones[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Observaciones 
,XC.value('Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Usuario_UltimaModificacion   
,XC.value('Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación[1]', 'varchar(500)') as NombresUsuario_UltimaModificacion 
,XC.value('Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Modificación[1]', 'varchar(500)') as ApellidosUsuario_UltimaModificacion 
,XC.value('Usuario_x0020_Asignado[1]','varchar(500)') as UsuarioAsignado
,XC.value('Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Nombres_UsuarioAsignado
,XC.value('Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Asignado[1]','varchar(500)') as Apellidos_UsuarioAsignado 
,XC.value('Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Usuario_UltimaGestion 
,XC.value('Nombres_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as NombresUsuario_UltimaGestion
,XC.value('Apellidos_x0020_Usuario_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as ApellidosUsuario_UltimaGestion
,XC.value('EtiquetaCallCopyUser3[1]','varchar(500)') as EtiquetaCallCopyUser_3 
,XC.value('EtiquetaCallCopyUser4[1]', 'varchar(500)') as EtiquetaCallCopyUser_4 
,XC.value('EtiquetaCallCopyUser10[1]', 'varchar(500)') as EtiquetaCallCopyUser_10   
,XC.value('EtiquetaCallCopyUser11[1]', 'varchar(500)') as EtiquetaCallaCopyUser_11 
,XC.value('EtiquetaCallCopyUser12[1]', 'varchar(500)') as EtiquetaCallCopyUser_12
,XC.value('EtiquetaCallCopyUser13[1]', 'varchar(500)') as EtiquetaCallCopyUser_13 
,XC.value('Fecha_x0020_Creación[1]', 'varchar(500)') as FechaCreación
,XC.value('Hora_x0020_Creación[1]', 'varchar(500)') as HoraCreacion 
,XC.value('Grupo_x0020_Inicia_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]','varchar(500)') as GrupoInicia_UltimaGestion
,XC.value('Grupo_x0020_Finaliza_x0020_Última_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GrupoFinaliza_UltimaGestion
,XC.value('Origen[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Origen 
,XC.value('Versión_x0020_Encuesta[1]', 'varchar(500)') as VersionEncuesta
,XC.value('Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Fecha_VersionEncuesta 
,XC.value('Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Encuesta[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Hora_VersionEncuesta 
,XC.value('Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Version_EstructuraCarga
,XC.value('Fecha_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga[1]', 'varchar(500)') as FechaVersion_EstructuraCarga 
,XC.value('Hora_x0020_Versión_x0020_Estructura_x0020_de_x0020_Carga[1]', 'varchar(500)') as HoraVersion_EstructuraCarga   
,XC.value('Estado_x0020_QA[1]','varchar(500)') as Estado_QA
,XC.value('Grupo_x0020_Negocio[1]','varchar(500)') as GrupoNegocio 
,XC.value('Grupo_x0020_Llamada[1]', 'varchar(500)') as GrupoLlamada 
,XC.value('Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Gestión[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TipoGestion 
,XC.value('CodCliente[1]','VARCHAR(500)') as CodCliente 
,XC.value('Nombre_x0020_Establecimiento[1]','varchar(500)') as NombreEstablecimiento
,XC.value('Responsable_x0020_Negocio[50]', 'varchar(500)') as ResponsableNegocio 
,XC.value('Tipo_x0020_de_x0020_Cliente_x0020__x0028_D_x002F_E_x0029_[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TipoCliente
,XC.value('ABC[1]', 'varchar(500)') as ABC 
,XC.value('Sector[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Sector 
,XC.value('Gerencia[1]','varchar(500)') as Gerencia 
,XC.value('Frecuencia_x0020_de_x0020_llamada[1]', 'varchar(500)') as FrecuenciaLlamada 
,XC.value('Telefono_x0020_Movil_x0020_1[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TelefonoMovil_1 
,XC.value('Telefono_x0020_Movil_x0020_2[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TelefonoMovil_2 
,XC.value('Telefono_x0020_Fijo_x0020_1[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TelefonoFijo_1 
,XC.value('Telefono_x0020_Fijo_x0020_2[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TelefonoFijo_2 
,XC.value('Telefono_x0020_Adicional_x0020__x0028_M_x0020_o_x0020_F_x0029_[1]', 'varchar(500)') as TelefonoAdicional 
,XC.value('Ciudad[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Ciudad 
,XC.value('Disponible1[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Disponible1
,XC.value('Disponible2[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Disponible2
FROM
@xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:GenerateReportResponse/ns:GenerateReportResult/Data/dg:diffgram/NewDataSet/Table') AS XT(XC)
```

But when executing it, it generates the following error 'The data type 'VARCHAR(500)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQeD2.jpg)' used in the VALUE method is invalid' Why is this happening? Help with this error. Thanks

Pdta: I'm sorry because the name of the fields is in Spanish but it's for a client who speaks Spanish

**UPDATED**

The error was on this line

```
XC.value ('CodCliente[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)[1]')
```

I already corrected it but the rows are empty, I changed `VARCHAR` for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQeD2.jpg)

Comment: `,XC.value('CodCliente[1]','VARCHAR(500)[1]') as CodCliente`.  That's a typo in the datatype, no?

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginninator", it doesn't need to (and shouldn't be) put before the `WITH`. Especially as you have terminated your precious statement properly. :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks, this was the problem, I did not notice this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is a bit weird. There are many namespaces involved... Namely the repeating declaration of a default namespaces (`xmlns="blah"` or `xmlns=""`) should be avoided.

However, I'd suggest this query:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap,
                    'http://tempuri.org' AS outerDflt,
                    'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' AS diffgr)
SELECT REPLACE(tblColumns.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(500)'),'_x0020_',' ') AS ElementKey
      ,tblColumns.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS ElementValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope
                 /soap:Body
                 /outerDflt:GenerateReportResponse
                 /outerDflt:GenerateReportResult
                 /outerDflt:Data
                 /diffgr:diffgram
                 /NewDataSet
                 /Table
                 /*') A(tblColumns);
```

The easy-cheesy approach, which would actually return the same, was this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(tblColumns.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(500)'),'_x0020_',' ') AS ElementKey
      ,tblColumns.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS ElementValue
FROM @xml.nodes('//Table/*') A(tblColumns);
```

The second works, because right before `<Table>` the default namespace is re-set to an empty namespace. If there is no other element `<Table>` within your structure the *deep search* to `//Table/*` will find all nodes below this element.

Both queries return this (you might use `_` instead of a blank to replace the *_x0020_*)

```
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| ElementKey                              | ElementValue         |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Registro                                | 1                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Campania                                | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Instancia                               | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Intentos                                | 4                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Duración Total                          | 236                  |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Duración Preview                        | 243                  |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Duración Llamada                        | 0                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Estado Registro                         | Registro Gestionado  |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Estado de la Última Gestión             | No Efectivo          |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Último Teléfono Marcado                 | *******              |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Bonificación de la Última Gestión       | 0                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Gestión Nivel 1                         | CERRADO POR INTENTOS |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Fecha Gestión                           | 16/05/2019           |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Hora Gestión                            | 18:42:29             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Usuario Última Modificación             | ********             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Nombres Usuario Última Modificación     | *******              |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Apellidos Usuario Última Modificación   | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Usuario Asignado                        | ******               |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Nombres Usuario Asignado                | ******               |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Apellidos Usuario Asignado              | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Usuario Última Gestión                  | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Nombres Usuario Última Gestión          | *******              |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Apellidos Usuario Última Gestión        | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Fecha Creación                          | 16/05/2019           |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Hora Creación                           | 09:43:29             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Grupo Finaliza Última Gestión           | SALUDO               |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Origen                                  | Archivo de Carga     |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Versión Encuesta                        | 1                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Fecha Versión Encuesta                  | 17/08/2016           |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Hora Versión Encuesta                   | 14:56:05             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Versión Estructura de Carga             | 4                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Fecha Versión Estructura de Carga       | 08/02/2019           |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Hora Versión Estructura de Carga        | 08:48:00             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Estado QA                               | Ninguno              |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Tipo de Gestión                         | ******               |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| CodCliente                              | *****                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Nombre Establecimiento                  | **********           |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Responsable Negocio                     | ********             |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Tipo de Cliente _x0028_D_x002F_E_x0029_ | ***                  |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| ABC                                     | ***                  |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Gerencia                                | ******               |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Frecuencia de llamada                   | *********            |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Ciudad                                  | *********            |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Disponible1                             | *******              |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Disponible2                             | *********            |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi change the value varchar to nvarchar `XC.value('CodCliente[1]','VARCHAR(500)[1]')` to
`XC.value('CodCliente[1]',N'NVARCHAR(500)[1]')` Because varchar doesn't  support characters.

[help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This was the problem, I did not notice this. Now it works but it does not add any value to me in the rows, they are empty.

Comment: hi try NCHAR and NVARCHAR(max). I rather think this value is not getting selected from the xml string. and put datatype like this N'NVARCHAR(max)[1]'

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error 'The data type 'nvarchar(max)[1]' used in the VALUE method is invalid.' I did it like that  XC.value('CodCliente[1]', N'nvarchar(max)[1]')

Comment: I think this is related to value selection from xml tags.

Comment: try put `XC.value('CodCliente[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')` hope this will fix the issue

Comment: This works but the rows are empty, I don't understand why